# Image upload and Preview on product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, image-upload, file-upload

How can a customer upload an image and then show the product as a preview and maybe customize it?

Comment: Magento version ?

Comment: Can you please explain more about your question?

Comment: Hello i sell some canvases. And  besides the default photos that the customer can choose, i want them to be able to upload their photos and be able to customize the images and preview them in the preview section on the project.

Comment: Magento Version 2.1 @Keyur Shah

Comment: @KeyurShah Version is 2.1